# Some questions about implementation of nullptr in Effective C++ by Scott Meyers, Second Edition?

Tags: c++

```
const // It is a const object...
class nullptr_t 
{
  public:
    template<class T>
    inline operator T*() const // convertible to any type of null non-member pointer...
    { return 0; }

    template<class C, class T>
    inline operator T C::*() const   // or any type of null member pointer...
    { return 0; }

  private:
    void operator&() const;  // Can't take address of nullptr

} nullptr = {};
```

1. `operator T*() const` and `operator T C::*() const` are already defined in class, so it can inline automatically. So, why add `inline` again?
2. why `void operator&() const;`, not`void operator&() = delete`?
3. what does `nullptr = {};` mean?

Comment: 1. Some compilers, like MSVC, have an option "only inline functions marked `inline`". Might be useful in debug mode.

Comment: If you have `= delete;`, you probably have `nullptr`.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

1. Adding the extra inline is a matter of style. That specifier has to do with linkage and ODR violations, not actual inlining. All inline member function definitions and template member functions in general have that specifier *implicitly*. I assume Scott Meyers added it there for pedagogical reasons.
2. Effective C++ was written for C++03 originally. There was no `= delete` back then. Declaring but not defining a function was all you could do back then.
3. This is aggregate initialization. This implementation of `nullptr_t` can be initialized like that even in C++03. It creates the value of `nullptr`. Since `nullptr_t` doesn't have a user provided default c'tor, it's required.

Comment: Is the aggregate initialization even needed? `nullptr_t` doesn't have any state/variables at all, so there is nothing to initialize, no?

Comment: @Rakete1111 - The variable is `const` (hidden at line 1) so it has to have an initializer.

Comment: @BoPersson - You are correct. The missing user defined c'tor completely slipped my mind.

Comment: @BoPersson Can you explain what does `The variable is const (hidden at line 1) so it has to have an initializer. `means? I'm also not familiar with this concept, thx!

Comment: @czxyl - The declared `nullptr` is a constant (the `const` keyword is placed in a valid, but unusual position). As you cannot assign a value to a constant later, a constant must always be given a value when defined. The class has no member variables, so its value looks empty - `= {}`.

Comment: Thanks! So it is syntax sugar and just the same as `class nullptr_t {...}; const nullptr_t nullptr = {};`?     Is there anywhere I have to use `const myclass{...}variable = {...}`?` and what is its best practice?

Comment: @czxyl - That is a subject for an entirely different post. Debating in comments is frowned upon on SO.

Comment: I have post question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46132652/several-questions-about-const-myclass-private-public-protect-vari) thanks for your suggestion!